# Geospacial query in Java-based database

Tags: java, database, geospatial

Suppose I only have this API that the [database](https://github.com/jetbrains/xodus) have provided to do a Geo spacial query to find which records/entities in the database are nearby a certain Geo-location point at a given distance.

```java
EntityIterable entities = txn.find(entityType, propertyName, minValue, maxValue);
```

Where the minValue and maxValue are Java `Comparable`. A trivial example non-geo spacial use for this is for finding, for instance, price range:

```java
EntityIterable entities = txn.find("Book", "price", 10.00, 20.00);
```

Which will return all entries which has a price tag of `10.00` to `20.00`

Now, if I have a `GeoPoint`

```java
public class GeoPoint implements Comparable, Serializable {
  private Double longitude;
  private Double latitude;
}
```

And saving it to the database like this:

```java
Entity book = txn.createEntity("Book");
book.setProperty("price", 15.00)
book.setProperty("geoLocation, new GeoLocation(theLongitude, theLatitude));
```

And would like to query like:

```java
EntityIterable entities = txn.find("Book", "geoLocation", minGeo, maxGeo);
```

Obviously, this query is quite linear, and I understand that the reason the Book price example works is that the `Double` value is a `Comparable` thus the MIN-MAX query would be able to compare from the `price`s from all entities in the database with the min and max value provided in the query.

However in the case of a Geo spacial query, it's quite different. **My question is how should I build the GeoPoint class as such it may be possible to be compared to using a min max function?**

Is there a way to *hack* a solution to be able to linearly query a Geo location. Maybe adding some hard-coded point of reference before saving the GeoPoint to the database?

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to do this is to use some space-filling curve, like Hilbert Curve. A [space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) maps a point on 2D plane to a point on real interval.

Google S2 library is adaptation of the idea for sphere and uses [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve). [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) uses [Z-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) for similar idea on 2D map.

For search queries using single min & max is not always optimal, but you may typically build a small list of intervals, and search for those.

Comment: How can you query with min-max with such approach?

Comment: Basically, you build a circle centered at your center point and your search radius, and see what intervals of the space-filling curve cross this circle. It might be a single interval or a few of them. Get the min/max of the intervals, and search for points inside any of the intervals. You can use an existing library, like GeoHash or Google's S2.

Comment: @michael-entil can you explain it in the form of `EntityIterable entities = txn.find("Book", "geoLocation", min, max);` I mean how would the solution you propose fits in this context?

Comment: Check the links I've added. A position on the curve is logically described by a single real number (translated to integer in S2 or a string in GeoHash). Given circle on the map, you'll know min/max value for the position on the curve where it crosses this circle, then use these min/max values. 
The most trivial (it is not exact - might miss points, but still widely used) query is `GeoHash(location, precision) = GeoHash(center, precision)`.

Comment: So GeoHash can be a `java.util.Comparable`?

Comment: Geohash value is a string.